# How to change pre font family to default Bootstrap 5 one?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

The default font for <pre> tags in Bootstrap 5 is a monospaced font, as it should be. However, I want to use a pre tag for a poem to preserve the line breaks, and I want the pre tag to use the default Bootstrap 5 sans-serif font, not the monospaced one. How do I do this without copy/pasting whatever Bootstrap does with its CSS?

I see that Bootstrap 5 has [a class for using a monospaced font family](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/text/#monospace):

```html
<p class="font-monospace">This is in monospace</p>
```

What I need is the opposite, something like `font-default`.

Comment: I know little about *bootstrap*, but it seems you want your `<pre>` to use *bootstrap* `font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family)`. 'Inspect' a paragraph with regular, *sans-serif* text on the link you gave for `font-family` with *DevTools*.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thank you, that's probably as close as I can get right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class names to your `pre` element to override the font stack. In the snippet below, I added `.poem` class with a non-monospace font to `pre` tag. See how it compares to `text-monospace` class.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.poem {
  font-family: cursive;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: #f0f0f0;  
}
.poem.inherit {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="text-monospace">This is in monospace</p>

<pre class="poem inherit">
What
is
a Fib?
A poem
mathematical
Syllables are arranged in lines
according to Fibonacci's sequence of numbers:
One, one, two, three, five, eight, thirteen, twenty-one, thirty-four, fifty-five and so on.
</pre>

<pre class="poem">
What
is
a Fib?
A poem
mathematical
Syllables are arranged in lines
according to Fibonacci's sequence of numbers:
One, one, two, three, five, eight, thirteen, twenty-one, thirty-four, fifty-five and so on.
</pre>
```

Comment: I was asking how to get the exact font family and font family fallbacks that Bootstrap uses. I'm guessing that Rene's comment on the OP is as close as I can get right now.

Comment: I understand. Looking at [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/reboot/#native-font-stack), it uses native/system font stack (i.e. `system-ui`, `-apple-system`, etc). You could certainly use their variable to override `pre` tag's monospace font. Or, you could also simply set `font-family: inherit` to inherit and use the parent style, which was what I suggested here. In any case, have a great day!

Comment: You're correct! I misread the inherit part. That actually works well in my case. Thank you!